# Test conversion of Ruby object into a json object with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have an object with say four attributes;

```
Object
attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4
```

I need to send this info to another app for Data Science reasons. I create a method that does the mapping:

```
def convert_for_elastic_search
    {
        name_attr1: @object.attr1,
        name_attr2: @object.attr2,
        name_attr3: @object.attr3
    }
end
```

How can I test this method with RSpec? I can't mock and I don't want to hardcode the values, since they come from Factory Bot.

Which is the better approach?

Comment: do `attr1`, `attr2` and `attr3` get autogenerated with FactoryBot ?, or are you assigning them values when you create the object in RSpec ?

Comment: They come from FactoryBot

Comment: How is `@object` available inside `convert_for_elastic_search`? Is the method defined on `Object`? It would be helpful to know a little bit more about how your code and tests are structured.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to somehow obtain a reference to `@object`.  If it is created using a create() call then you can override attributes from the factory.

If you can't set the values directly then you could create expectations that validate that the 'mapped' values match the source values.

```
object { FactoryBot.create(:object) }
subject { FactoryBot.create(:mapper, object: object) }
```

```
result = subject.convert_for_elastic_search
expect(result[:name_attr1]).to eq object.attr1
expect(result[:name_attr2]).to eq object.attr2
expect(result[:name_attr3]).to eq object.attr3
```

Of course if you are setting up the spec as shown above then it would be trivial to set hardcoded values. i.e. `FactoryBot.create(:object, attr1: 'val1')`.  In which case you can just expect 'val1'.

If `object` is not accessible as shown above then you'd need a way to get a reference to it, perhaps the mapper (subject) exposes this somehow.

If you really can't get at `@object` then perhaps just testing the value is present & of the correct data type would be enough to validate the mapping process.